# How to set a value(correlationId) and make it accessible throughout a method execution (similar to accessing values from HttpContext) in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpcontext

I am trying to implement something similar to a correlationId, where all the methods have access to the header from HttpContext object and uses the correlationId for logging.

Except the code I am trying to execute is not triggered by a Http request. It resides in a background service and runs continuously for every 10 min.
Below is an minimal example.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            await _myService.PerformSomeOperations(item);
        }
        await Task.Delay(10 * 1000);   
    }
}
```

The PerformSomeOperations method internally might call multiple methods from many different classes. This will result in a lot of logs.

I want to be able to identify all the logs coming in from a certain PerformSomeOperations() call. And I want to do it without modifying all the method signatures to include a correlationId parameter and pass it along throughout the chain of calls.

Also, we might be performing the PerformSomeOperations() in parallel in the near future. Then the existing logs would mixup and we need something to identify all the logs coming under a single PerformSomeOperations() call.

Any help or leads with how to implement a viable solution is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
Please note that I am using log4net for logging.

Comment: Need more details. Is this a `BackgroundService` or are you implementing `IHostedService` yourself? If you want to associate with a correlationId but you don’t want to pass it in, where is it going to come from?

Comment: Incidentally you can [pass a TimeSpan to Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0) which is much more readable than passing in multiplied integers as milliseconds. Also wondering why you’re not passing the cancellation token to that?

Comment: It is a BackgroundService which is internally implementing the IHostedService. Please ignore the delay.. It's just a sample @stuartd

If you want to associate with a correlationId but you don’t want to pass it in, where is it going to come from?
-> Just the way it comes from the headers in the case of HttpContext and is available throughout the request lifecycle. Hoping there would be some way to assign and read a value similarly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `ILogger.BeginScope` is for. Its API is not very obvious; see [this blog post](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/) for usage details.

In summary, it looks like this:

```cs
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>() { ["CorrelationId"] = correlationId }))
{
  // All log messages in here have a CorrelationId automatically applied.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's my bad that I have not mentioned that I use log4net for logging.
But after looking for BeginScope alternatives for log4net, I have come across few leads that I can followup.

Comment: I really wish that `ILogger.BeginScope` was better-known.

Comment: @AnudeepSai: I have used a log4net provider for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging successfully. If you only use log4net, then use `LogicalThreadContext`, and I recommend using an `IDisposable` API with it.